# Detect if remote page changed

Tags: ruby

I need to detect if a remote page changed. I wrote:

```
a = JSON.parse open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page').read
b = JSON.parse open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page').read
```

The page was not changed, but `a == b` returned `false`. Is it possible to detect if the page changed or not?

Comment: Strangely I have `a == b # => true`. Show the whole code?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you put `JSON.parse` there for?? Do you expect the wikipedia mainpage to be json-encoded?

```
require 'open-uri'
a = open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page').read
b = open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page').read
puts a == b
# ⇒ true
```

Whether you have the dynamically created pages (produced by CMS or likewise), you need to examine the web page content and explicitly cast the page to, say, canonical view: cut all the temporary information off and compare the static parts only.

Comment: Please wait 5-10 sec before b = open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page').read and puts a == b will be
# ⇒ false

Comment: Well, I did. I don’t trust the woodoo rites. `a` and `b` here are just the strings after all. Neither headers, nor another HTTP-related stuff can not garble the result. Whether there were no modifications to the page made, the comparision of the results returns `true`. Period.

Comment: I feel like a fool... But I'm not making this up. Here's another example:

a = open('https://sjobs.brassring.com/TGWebHost/jobdetails.aspx?jobId=167273&partnerid=25354&siteid=5108&codes=AD007').read

b = a = open('https://sjobs.brassring.com/TGWebHost/jobdetails.aspx?jobId=167273&partnerid=25354&siteid=5108&codes=AD007').read

a == b # => false

Comment: Arghhh. Those pages are dynamically created; they include `sessionid` and other session-specific stuff within. Try `wget PAGE -O 1.html && sleep 5 && wget PAGE -O 2.html && diff 1.html 2.html` (or _SaveAs…_ from browser if you’re on Windows) and you’ll see these session ids etc. As a workaround here you need to examine the web page content and explicitly cast the page to, say, canonical view: cut all the temporary information off and compare the static parts only.

Comment: I wanted to hear it. Only the static page(part page). Thank you!